# How many license plates could begin with A and end with Zero

Tags: functions

Suppose that  in a certain state , all automobile license plates have four letters followed by three digits.
A)  How many license plates could begin with  A and end with Zero
B)  How many plates are possible in which all the letters and digits are distinct?

Comment: Have you tried something? Imho, this sounds like homework.

Comment: Can I edit the tags?

Comment: To get you on the road. How many letters exists and how many digits. Next, how many combinations of two letter can you come up with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you drawn a picture? It's usually quite a good strategy. In case a) the picture is something like

$$A,\_,\_,\_,|\_,\_,0$$

You have 26 choices for each of the first 3 empty slots and 10 choices for the remaining 2 slots. I'm guessing you can take it from here.

For case b) you have 26 choices for the first slot
$$26,\_,\_,\_,|\_,\_,\_$$

The next slot must be different from the previous so there are 25 choices for the next slot
$$26,25,\_,\_,|\_,\_,\_$$

Can you finish it off?

Comment: for  B)  26,25,24,23| 2,1,0 ?

Comment: for A) = A,26,25,24|2,1,0?

Comment: Not sure where the 2,1 is coming from. You have 10 choices for the digits. For a) there are 10 digits to choose from for each remaining digit slot. For b) you have 10 choices for the first digit slot and 9 choices for the next etc.

Comment: For a) that means "A",26,26,26|10,10,"0" so there are $26^3\cdot 10^2$. Can you do b) ?

Comment: B) 26,25,24,23|10,9,0

Comment: @HeeganHero nearly there. The last 0 should be an 8.